# Get every row in a dataframe whose column value matches a list: Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, match, series

I have a dataframe with stock price data that looks like this:

```
    Company  Date    Price
0   RSG.AX   2011    0.814 
1   RSG.AX   2010    0.889 
2   RSG.AX   2009    0.937 
3   RSG.AX   2008    0.181 
4   RSG.AX   2007    0.216 
5   RSG.AX   2006    0.494 
6   QBE.AX   2011    7.119 
7   QBE.AX   2010    8.331 
8   QBE.AX   2009    8.961 
9   QBE.AX   2008    9.159 
10  QBE.AX   2007    9.156
11  FER.AX   2011    2.165 
12  FER.AX   2010    3.324 
13  FER.AX   2009    3.453 
14  FER.AX   2008    2.969 
15  FER.AX   2007    3.422
```

I also have a series of company names that I am trying to match to this dataframe and pull out the data that matches.

For instance, the series contains companies QBE.AX and FER.AX, but not RSG.AX, so I want to pull out every QBE.AX and FER.AX row in the dataframe.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a fairly common question, so it would be helpful to see what you've tried so far based on your own research, and what was wrong with your attempts

Comment: The first thing I tried was:

df_new = df[df['Company'] in ['QBE.AX', 'FER.AX']]

which, of course, failed with:  *** ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
df_new = df[df['Company'].isin(['QBE.AX', 'FER.AX'])]
```